# What is the FAQ tab?

Tags: support

How are questions featured in the [FAQ tab](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=faq) chosen?

Is there an automated process or do the mods choose them depending on their FAQ value?

Comment: tag or tab? Could you be more specific? Do you mean what's on the [faq] page?

Comment: Sorry, wrong word in the title. Also added a hyperlink.

Comment: What’s the FAQ tab? This seems to be a feature that was removed from SE.

Comment: @Jan FAQ is now called the [help].

Answer (score 4):

It's done automatically based on votes and views and links between questions, and possibly other factors.

The question has been asked before on meta.SO and the exact formula is never revealed.